# UIView.frame is incorrect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

In a test setup I have a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController` with a `UIPageControl` constrained to the bottom with a fixed height of 37. Between the `UINavigationController` and `UIPageControl` is a `UIScrollView` constrained to the bottom and top respectively.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("view.bounds \(view.bounds)")
    print("view.frame \(view.frame)")

    print("navbar.bounds \((navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds)!)")
    print("navbar.frame \((navigationController?.navigationBar.frame)!)")

    print("scrollView.bounds \(scrollView.bounds)")
    print("scrollView.frame \(scrollView.frame)")

    print("pageControl.bounds \(pageControl.bounds)")
    print("pageControl.frame \(pageControl.frame)")
}
```

Yields:

> view.bounds (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
>   view.frame (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0)
>   navbar.bounds (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 44.0)
>   navbar.frame (0.0, 20.0, 375.0, 44.0)
>   scrollView.bounds (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 499.0)
>   scrollView.frame (0.0, 64.0, 600.0, 499.0)
>   pageControl.bounds (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 37.0)
>   pageControl.frame (0.0, 563.0, 600.0, 37.0)

The view loads as it should with the `UIPageControl` at the very bottom with the `UIScrollView` stretching all the way to its top.

So why is the printout giving me an incorrect result?

I.e. if view height = 667, the status bar height = 20, the navbar height = 44 & the page control height = 37

667 - 20 - 44 - 37 = 556 (!= 499)

So the scroll view height is wrong and also the `UIPageControl.frame` is wrong!

Furthermore:

```
let pageControlView = UIView(frame: pageControl.frame)
pageControlView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() 

let window: UIWindow! = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate?.window)!
window.addSubview(pageControlView)
window.bringSubviewToFront(pageControlView)
```

positions `pageControlView` above where the `UIPageControl` is... What is going on here I'm very confused!

**Edit:**

This is what I get for Landscape orientation:

> view.bounds (0.0, 0.0, 667.0, 375.0)
>   view.frame (0.0, 0.0, 667.0, 375.0)
>   navbar.bounds (0.0, 0.0, 667.0, 32.0)
>   navbar.frame (0.0, 0.0, 667.0, 32.0)
>   scrollView.bounds (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 499.0)
>   scrollView.frame (0.0, 64.0, 600.0, 499.0)
>   pageControl.bounds (0.0, 0.0, 600.0, 37.0)
>   pageControl.frame (0.0, 563.0, 600.0, 37.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autolayout does not finish calculating frames until `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. If you want to do something before the view appears, move anything that requires a complete frame to there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it 's because your view is under top bars. 
try:

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
 {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
 }
```